# For loop over function parameters oddity in C++

Tags: c++

In my current project I stumbled upon a weird phenomenon where a nested for-loop would only execute the inner loop once and then simply stop. Even after careful inspection of all variables involved, the outer for-loop still terminated without due reason. The only thing that made this construction different from other for-loops contained in my program was the fact that the counter variable was passed as a parameter to the function containing the loop and never copied anywhere.

So I decided to test if the problem can be reproduced:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void someFunction(int x, int y, int width, int length)
{
    int endX = x+width;
    int endY = y+length;

    printf("x will not exceed: %i\n", endX);
    printf("y will not exceed: %i\n", endY);

    for(; x < endX; x++)
    {
        for(; y < endY; y++)
        {
            printf("(%i, %i)\n", x, y);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    someFunction(1, 1, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Upon execution, however, the output of the application differs from intuitive expection:

```
x will not exceed: 6
y will not exceed: 6
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
```

The behavior is similar when x and y are switched, but with the y variable never being incremented. The problem is solved by simply declaring a new variable as the counter for each of the loops.

But why does this happen? Is it disallowed for a specific reason? Does the compiler disable modification of certain parameters and if so, why does it work with one variable but not the other?

The source code provided was compiled with GCC/G++ 4.5.3 without any special optimization flags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`y` is never being reset within the `x` loop, so once it goes out of bounds on the first pass it stays out of bounds forevermore.

Comment: Well that was simple enough. Guess it's bedtime for me now.

Answer (score 2):

Since `x` and `y` exist also outside the loop and since the loop don't set their initial value, they retain the last value even when reused.
This, in particular, is about your `y`, that does not rewind to the initial value after the y-loop exit.

To avoid this kind of problem, avoid to use variables external to a loop as indexes.

```
void someFunction(const int x, const int y, const int width, const int length)
{
    int endX = x+width;
    int endY = y+length;

    printf("x will not exceed: %i\n", endX);
    printf("y will not exceed: %i\n", endY);

    for(int ix=x; ix < endX; ++ix)
    {
        for(int iy=0; iy < endY; ++iy)
        {
            printf("(%i, %i)\n", ix, iy);
        }
    }
}
```

HEre, by making the parameter const we ensure we cannot touch them, even by mistake. Then we use ix and iy local to the loops to handle iterations.

Also, unless you must for some other reason, avoid to use the postfix increment, and use prefix. Until you are using integers it's not a big change, but with more complex variables can make the difference.

It will also be a good idea (since you tagged the question as `C++` and not `C`) if you avoid to code like a C programmer.

The idiomatic C++ equivalent is this:

```
#include <iostream>

void someFunction(const int& x, const int& y, const int& width, const int& length)
{
    const int endX = x+width;
    const int endY = y+length;

    std::cout << "x will not exceed: " << endX << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y will not exceed: " << endY << std::endl;

    for(int ix=x; ix < endX; ++ix)
    {
        for(int iy=y; iy < endY; ++iy)
        {
            std::cout << '('<<ix<<", "<<iy<<')'<< std::endl;    
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    someFunction(1, 1, 5, 5);
    return 0;
}
```